# upload mesh QML

Tags: qt, qml, blender

I'am new to Qt and I am trying to upload a mesh (.obj) in my QML file but it does not work. no error and no results.
how can I make it work.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Logic 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0
import Qt3D.Animation 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2



Viewport{
    id:viewroot
    normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0, 0, 1, 1)

   Entity {
        id: sceneRoot
        Mesh{
            id:carmesh
            source:"Bibliothèques\Documents\mercedes.obj"
        }


}


}
```

Comment: There are two things which look suspicious to me: 1. the `è` in `Bibliothèques` (correct encoding?) 2. the backslashs (can be replaced by `/`). I would start with these two issues first before digging deeper... Regarding 1.: I assume QML has to be encoded in UTF-8. So, ensure that your editor uses UTF-8 as well and check whether the `è` is still an `è`. E.g. I set my Notepad++ encoding to "ANSI", then typed an `è`, then changed to "UTF-8 (without BOM)". The `è` became an `xE8` which is not `è` anymore (and even no valid UTF-8 code at all). Or, simply use a path with ASCIIs only for testing.

Comment: it didn't work because of the big size of the mesh , when uploading only  some part of the mesh it worked.i've changed the path under qrc .

Comment: OK. This is not exposed in your source code and even if it were - I hardly had recognized it... ;-) Regarding "not working": Are you sure it (really) didn't work with the big file? I always try to convince my tester colleagues that there's a big difference whether something crashs or (in opposition) hangs (because some computations simply need so long and the application is unresponsive during that time but still runs fine and will become eventually responsive again afterwards).

Comment: the size problem appeared when i changed the path under qrc. i fixed it (out of memory allocating... bytes) by adding CONFIG +=resources_big in my .pro file and yes it runs fine but does not display the mesh.so i tried to upload a part of it and it did work.the problem now is i have to split the mesh into several parts to be uploaded and each part should be under a new qrc file .that does not seem to be a good solution.